# Error creating bean while using Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple Springboot application in which I am trying to use in memory HashMap as a DB to store some info.
This is my restcontroler

```
    @RestController
public class Parking {

    @Autowired
    ParkingServices parkingServices;

    @Autowired
    Vehicle vehicle;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void park() {
        vehicle = Vehicle.builder().color("Blue").plateNumber("qwew").build();
        parkingServices.parkCar(vehicle);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public void Test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

This is my simple parking service

```
   @Service
public class ParkingServices {

    @Autowired
    ParkingLotService parkingLot;

    public ParkingServices() {
        parkingLot.init(10);
    }

    public int parkCar(Vehicle vehicle) {
        return parkingLot.parkCar(vehicle);
    }
}
```

And this is my ParkingLot service

```
  @Service
public class ParkingLotService {
    private int size = 0;
    private HashMap<Integer, Slot> parkingSlots = new HashMap<>();
    private Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();

    public void init(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        parkingSlots = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            parkingSlots.put(i, new ParkingSlot());
            st.push(i);
        }
    }

    public int parkCar(Vehicle vehicle) {
        int firstPark = st.pop();
        Slot slot = parkingSlots.get(firstPark);
        slot.parkVehicle(vehicle);
        parkingSlots.put(firstPark, slot);
        return firstPark;
    }

    public void removeCar(int parkingNumber) {
        Slot slot = parkingSlots.get(parkingNumber);

    }
}
```

Now when i try to run the application I am getting this error as a stack trace

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parking': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'parkingServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parkingServices' defined in file [D:\Projects\parking\demo\target\classes\com\parking\demo\Services\ParkingServices.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.parking.demo.Services.ParkingServices]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.parking.demo.ParkingApplication.main(ParkingApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parkingServices' defined in file [D:\Projects\parking\demo\target\classes\com\parking\demo\Services\ParkingServices.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.parking.demo.Services.ParkingServices]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.parking.demo.Services.ParkingServices]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:225) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.parking.demo.Services.ParkingServices.<init>(ParkingServices.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

I know its due to Autowired is not working on ParkingLotService, its ability to work if instead of Autowired in ParkingService, I directly try to initialize Object but not the other way around.
Can someone help me with it ? Why Autowired is not working and how to make it work.

Comment: In this code --->public ParkingServices() {parkingLot.init(10);}, parkingLot is not instantiated and you are using it's reference hence it's failing to load.

Comment: You are accessing the service in the constructor which isn't possible as it will be autowired after the object has been constructed.

Comment: Calling `init` is btw a bad idea, because if you use this in multiple classes this will lead to issues. The service is a singleton shared between those classes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spring** `@Autowired` field injection after construction invoked.

See:

```
Autowired Fields
Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. Such a config field does not have to be public.
```

[Spring Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)

So for your scenario, you can use:

1. Autowired Constructors to inject `ParkingLotService` and invoke the `init` method.

```
    @Autowired
    public ParkingServices(ParkingLotService parkingLot) {
        parkingLot.init(10);
        this.parkingLot = parkingLot;
    }
```

2. use `@PostConstruct` method to invoke the `init` method

```
@PostConstruct
public void myInit() {
  parkingLot.init(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: **Use Constructor-based DI**

1. move the `@Autowired` atop constructor
2. add field as parameter to constructor and assign therein first

### Error Analysed

You got this `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` because:

> Error creating bean with name 'parking':

This *bean* could not be created because:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'parkingServices';

So the field **could not be autowired** by Spring with a dependency because of a *NullPointerException (NPE)*:

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException

---

Continue to answer explaining [M. Deinum comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103066/error-creating-bean-while-using-autowired/67103151#comment118611871_67103151):

> The problem is the accessing of a variable before it is available.

---

The NPE was raised when the constructor of `ParkingServices` tries to call `init` on the field `parkingLot`, because the field was `null`.

```java
@Autowired
ParkingLotService parkingLot; // field autowired in 2nd step

public ParkingServices() {
    parkingLot.init(10);      // constructor called in 1st step, hence NPE
}
```

#### Spring's `@Autowired` Explained

Spring's `@Autowired` is a Java-annotation to facilitate Dependency-Injection (DI).

Spring as most DI-frameworks offers 3 different ways of DI:

1. Constructor-based DI
2. Field-based DI
3. Setter-based DI

In your case you use Field-based DI. This fails, because Spring **first calls** the constructor **before autowiring fields** (= injecting beans into Autowired annotated fields).

See the tutorial of *LogicBig* (2020): [Spring - Different ways of injecting dependencies](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/types-of-dependency-injection.html)
It shows a nice illustration:
[image: different DI forms]

#### Vicious circle of dependencies

Your constructor fails with a NPE, because it calls a method on a `null` field. The field is `null` because it was not yet instantiated, i.e. *autowired*. And it will not unless the constructor succeeds.

### Solution recommended

Use **Constructor-based** DI by adding the field as parameter to the constructor and moving the `@Autowired` annotation form field to constructor.

```java
ParkingLotService parkingLot; // field autowired by constructor in 1nd step

@Autowired   // tells Spring to inject suitable beans for parameters
public ParkingServices(ParkingLotService parkingLot) {  // add field as required dependency
    this.parkingLot = parkingLot;  // instantiate field
    this.parkingLot.init(10);      // call init on non-null field, avoid NPE
}
```

#### Benefits

This way you can instantiate and call `init` methods on the field in the same code block. So related code is near in scope, near to understand, near to maintain.

See the comparison of DI-methods and their benefis in *Rizvi's* Blog:
[Different Types of Bean Injection in Spring](https://zakirrizvi.blogspot.com/2017/11/different-types-of-bean-injection-in_27.html):

### [image: Field- VS Constructor-Injection]

### Bonus Review

As [M. Deinum commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103066/error-creating-bean-while-using-autowired/67103151#comment118610685_67103066) on your question:

> Calling `init` is btw a bad idea, because if you use this in multiple classes this will **lead to issues**. The service is a **singleton** shared between those classes...

(bold emphasis by me)

This **side-effect** could be solved by "initializing" the `ParkingLotService` right away in its constructor, like:

```java
public ParkingLotService(int size) {  // former init
    this.size = size;
    this.parkingSlots = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        this.parkingSlots.put(i, new ParkingSlot());
        this.freeParkStack.push(i);     // renamed `st` to `freeParkStack`
    }
}
```

This way your *singleton* is "initialized" once, guaranteed and mandatory (because done with constructor, nobody will forget to init it).
If a re-initialisation (here resizing) is still needed, the code can be extracted into a separate method later.

General advices:

- always name your variables to express purpose (avoid abbreviations)
- prefix a classes fields with `this.` to distinguish them from parameters (also avoids compiler errors when same names assigned)

Get further review, tips and improvements! Post your *working* code on the sister-site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem is the accessing of a variable before it is available.