# java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException after upgrading spring boot from 2.3.2.RELEASE to 2.7.10. Using Java 11 [RESOLVED]

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-data-redis

I am getting the error below when running `gradle clean build` during JUnit execution.

- Spring-boot version: 2.7.10  (we want to use this version specifically to avoid vulnerabilities)
- Java: 11
- Gradle: 7.1.1 (using gradle wrapper)

Any help will be much appreciated as this is very critical for our project.
Notably this issue happens during bean initialization of jedisConnectionFactory inside RedisConfiguration looking at stack trace. This is failing only during JUnit specific to spring-boot 2.7.10 at the build time

After going through stack trace, can something be fixed  given in below link as an example?

[Error creating bean while using Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103066/error-creating-bean-while-using-autowired)

```
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/redis/connection/RedisConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334)

 Caused by:
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530      java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:59)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.168+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:52)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:93)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.computeReturnType(MethodRepository.java:75)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:66)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:292)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.PropertyInfo.get(PropertyInfo.java:285)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.ClassInfo.getProperties(ClassInfo.java:82)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetPropertyInfo(Introspector.java:515)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:463)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:294)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:236)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.getBeanInfo(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:252)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:277)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:181)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:174)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:248)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1594)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
2023-04-06T09:18:15.169+0530          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1434)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at com.myproject.redis.connection.RedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2544120a.jedisConnectionFactory(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at com.myproject.redis.connection.RedisConfiguration.redisTemplate(RedisConfiguration.java:63) ~[main/:?]
    at com.myproject.redis.connection.RedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2544120a.CGLIB$redisTemplate$0(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at com.myproject.redis.connection.RedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2544120a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e85ae083.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at com.myproject.redis.connection.RedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2544120a.redisTemplate(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeanByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:520) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:673) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:329) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
```

**RedisConfiguration:**

```
package com.redis.connection;


import javax.annotation.Resource;

import com.secretsmanagement.api.CredentialProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericToStringSerializer;
```

**RedisConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfiguration {

    private final String redisHost;
    private final int redisPort;
    private final String connectionPoolMaxTotal;
    private final String connectionPoolIdleTotal;

    @Resource(name = "eventStreamRedisCredentialProvider")
    private CredentialProvider credentialProvider;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisConfiguration.class);

    public RedisConfiguration(RedisProperties redisProperties){
        redisHost = redisProperties.getRedisHost();
        redisPort = redisProperties.getRedisPort();
        connectionPoolMaxTotal = redisProperties.getConnectionPoolMaxTotal();
        connectionPoolIdleTotal = redisProperties.getConnectionPoolIdleTotal();
    }

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() throws RedisConnectionFailureException{
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = null;
        try {
            RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(credentialProvider.getCredential().getPassword());
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(0);
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisHost);
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(redisPort);
            jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
            jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(connectionPoolMaxTotal));
            jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt(connectionPoolIdleTotal));
        } catch (RedisConnectionFailureException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to establish connection with redis");
            throw new RedisConnectionFailureException("Unable to establish connection with redis");
        }
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        return template;
    }
}
```

```
**RedisProperties.java:**

mport lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class RedisProperties {

    private int redisPort;
    private String redisHost;
    private String connectionPoolMaxTotal;
    private String connectionPoolIdleTotal;

    public RedisProperties(
            @Value("${spring.redis.port}") int redisPort,
            @Value("${spring.redis.host}") String redisHost,
            @Value("${redis.connection.pool.max.total}") String connectionPoolMaxTotal,
            @Value("${redis.connection.pool.idle.total}") String connectionPoolIdleTotal) {
        this.redisPort = redisPort;
        this.redisHost = redisHost;
        this.connectionPoolMaxTotal = connectionPoolMaxTotal;
        this.connectionPoolIdleTotal = connectionPoolIdleTotal;
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
apply from: "${rootDir}/build-support/packaging.gradle"
group = 'com.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15to18:1.69'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation ('redis.clients:jedis'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-pool2'
    }

    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: 'org.junit.jupiter', module: 'junit-jupiter'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testImplementation 'it.ozimov:embedded-redis:0.7.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    implementation ('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'){
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.4.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'com.project:secrets-management-vault-spring:1.5.93'
    implementation 'com.project:secrets-management-simple:1.5.93'
    implementation 'com.project:secrets-management-tls-common:1.5.93'
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'
    implementation 'net.wedjaa.ansible.vault:vault-utilities:1.2.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.properties:

```
app.version=1.0

server.port=8080
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379

redis.connection.pool.max.total=50
redis.connection.pool.idle.total=50

#Actuator endpoints configuration
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=status
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always


logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.pattern.console=%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %X{X-CorrelationId} %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}
logging.pattern.file=%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %X{X-CorrelationId} %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}
server.tomcat.basedir=/var/tmp/tomcat

spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

I made few changes as adding below config during this activity to avoid few errors but they seem not to be relevant for the current issue:

application.properties:

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

build.gradle:

```
dependency ('redis.clients:jedis') (removed version 3.1.0 which was mentioned earlier)
org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine  (added for backward compatibility)
```

Spring 2.3.2.RELEASE working fine without any issue with Java 11 but not working for 2.7.10.

Used below url for some reference :
https://blog.codecentric.de/migrating-spring-boot-java-17

Below are the junit classes in my project :

**EventsApplicationTests.java :**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class EventsApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

**EventsDataSourceProvider.java :**

```
@Resource
public class EventsDataSourceProvider {

    public List<String> getAuthenticationTypeEvents(){
        return this.getEventsFromFile("events_auth.txt");
    }

    public List<String> getAuthenticationTypeInvalidEvents(){ return this.getEventsFromFile("events_auth_invalid.txt"); }

    public List<String> getAllTypesEvents(){
        return this.getEventsFromFile("events.txt");
    }

    public List<String> getDocumentsTypesEvents(){
        return this.getEventsFromFile("events_documents.txt");
    }

    public List<String> getCorrespondenceTypesEvents(){
        return this.getEventsFromFile("events_correspondence.txt");
    }

    public List<String> getProjectsTypesEvents(){
        return this.getEventsFromFile("events_projects.txt");
    }

    private List<String> getEventsFromFile(String inputFile){
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(inputFile).getFile());

        List<String> events = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader eventBufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file.toURI()))) {
            events = eventBufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return events;
    }

}
```

**RedisConfigTest.java :**

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestRedisConfiguration.class)
public class RedisConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private EventStreamRepository eventStreamRepository;

    @Test
    private void testRedisConfiguration(){
        // TODO
    }
}
```

**EventStreamRepositoryTest.java :**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestRedisConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EventStreamRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private EventStreamRepository eventStreamRepository;
    @Resource
    private RedisConfiguration redisConfiguration;
    @Resource
    private EventsDataSourceProvider eventsDataSourceProvider;
    @Resource
    private EventsConversionUtil eventsConversionUtil;

    private String organizationId = "1879048492";

    @BeforeEach
    private void cleanUp() {
        redisConfiguration.redisTemplate().getConnectionFactory().getConnection().flushDb();
    }

    @Test
    public void saveEvents() {
        List<String> events = eventsDataSourceProvider.getAllTypesEvents();
        List<String> savedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        events.stream().forEach(event -> {
            EventDto eventDto = eventsConversionUtil.convertJsonStringToObject(event);
            savedEvents.add(eventStreamRepository.saveEvent(eventsConversionUtil.getEventIdIndexFromJson(event), organizationId,
                    eventsConversionUtil.convertDateToSeconds(eventDto.getTimestamp()), event, eventDto.getTimestamp()));
        });
        Assertions.assertEquals(savedEvents.size(), events.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllEventsForOrg() {
        cleanUp();
        List<String> events = eventsDataSourceProvider.getAllTypesEvents();
        List<String> savedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        events.stream().forEach(event -> {
            EventDto eventDto = eventsConversionUtil.convertJsonStringToObject(event);
            savedEvents.add(eventStreamRepository.saveEvent(eventsConversionUtil.getEventIdIndexFromJson(event), organizationId,
                    eventsConversionUtil.convertDateToSeconds(eventDto.getTimestamp()), event, eventDto.getTimestamp()));
        });

        List<String> eventsJson = eventStreamRepository.getAllEvents(organizationId);
        Assertions.assertEquals(eventsJson.size(), savedEvents.size());
    }
}
```

**TestRedisConfiguration.java :**

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestRedisConfiguration {

    private final RedisServer redisServer;

    public TestRedisConfiguration(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        this.redisServer = new RedisServer(redisProperties.getRedisPort());
    }

    @Bean
    EventsDataSourceProvider getEventsDataSourceProvider(){
        return new EventsDataSourceProvider();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        redisServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your RedisProperties from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.10/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisProperties.java, I can't compile with your `RedisConfiguration`.

Comment: @samabcde i added RedisProperties code file. let me know what else you need. As mentioned build is failing during junits.

Comment: @samabcde added junits as well for reference

Comment: Appreciate you add so many details, but did you even try to compile with what you are providing(what is `EventStreamRepository`)? Try take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
Base on what given, I can only suggest you to remove `exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-pool2'` and `implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.4.2'`(or change to 2.11.1 as required by jedis 3.8.0.

Comment: THE ISSUE GOT RESOLVED BY OTHERS AFTER REMOVING THE EXPLICIT DEPENDANCY OF commons-pool2 JAR AND REMOVING THE EXCLUDED TRANSITIVE DEPENDANCY FOR commons-pool2 WHEN DEFINED Jedis INSIDE build.gradle . This essentially means we should be using commons-pool2 of jedis instead of defining it separately.                                                                                "The malformed parameter exception was due to incompatible versions of common pool and jedis" fyi